# SQL: Query XML node value, exclude nested node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xquery, openxml

I'm having trouble importing a new XML format into our MS SQL database.
My document is looking similar to this.

```
<xml>
  <data>
    <email>test@mail.com</email>
    <isActive>
      true
      <previous>false</previous>
    </isActive>
  </data>
</xml>
```

My issue is that I cannot get the value 'true' for column "isActive" when attempting to query it it returns 'truefalse', the nested "previous" node is included. I cannot figure out how to exclude it or split it into 2 separate columns.

From what I understand this XML should be perfectly valid.

I've tried 2 approaches.
The current SQL statement that the files were imported with before the format update using OPENXML, I've tried to specify also here to take just the first instance of isActive, but the first instance of course includes the "previous" node as it's contained within the "isActive" node.

```
select
  email,
  isActive
from
  openxml(@xmlDocument, '/data')
  with
  (
    email nvarchar(128) 'email',
    isActive nvarchar(12) 'isActive[1]'
    --isActive nvarchar(12) 'isActive'
  )
```

Using xquery

```
select
  data.col.value('(email)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)'),
  data.col.value('(isActive)[1]', 'nvarchar(12)')
from
  @xmlDocument.nodes('/data') as data(col)
```

While the example appears to be working, it is actually including both values behind the scenes (due to linebreak)
If I attempt to convert it into boolean it shows the following.

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx6A0.png)

Comment: `data.col.value('xs:boolean((isActive/text())[1])', 'bit')`

Comment: perfect, this returns only 1 value and not the nested node.

Answer (score 0):

```
    You can do this:
    DECLARE @xmlDocument XML =' <data>
        <email>test@mail.com</email>
        <isActive>
          true
          <previous>false</previous>
        </isActive>
      </data>'
    
    select
      data.col.value('(email)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') AS [Email],
      data.col.value('(isActive)[1]', 'nvarchar(12)') AS [IsActive],
      data.col.value('(isActive/previous)[1]', 'nvarchar(12)') AS [IsActive_previous]
    from
      @xmlDocument.nodes('/data') as data(col)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]




select
  data.col.value('(email)[1]', 'nvarchar(128)') AS [Email],
  (CASE WHEN (data.col.value('(isActive)[1]', 'nvarchar(12)'))='false' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [IsActive],
  (CASE WHEN trim(data.col.value('(isActive/previous)[1]', 'nvarchar(12)'))='false' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS [IsActive_previous]
from
  @xmlDocument.nodes('/data') as data(col)
```

1st Query Result
[image]

2nd Query Result
[image]

Comment: I can see now that my own xquery example is basically what you wrote also and it works, I should have tested my test example. I've applied the same logic on the actual real data I have and it's still giving incorrect result. I will update the original question once I have anonymized the data.

Comment: Ah i figured it out now, your example is hiding the 2nd value, if i convert the true/false to boolean you'll see it yourself also.

`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '
      true
      false' to data type bit.`

Comment: SQL Server bit value is 1 or 0.  If you want the result should be a bit type value then use the case statement and get the value. I have added the details above.

Comment: SQL server accepts true/false as bit as well.
`select convert(bit, 1), convert(bit, 'true')`

Comment: You are right, But in your xml the value is in string format so getting a conversion failed error

Comment: I can see your example works, but i don't understand how since it seems to be returning both values still, i've added a screenshot to highlight the issue